# Scala AWS size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, aws-lambda

I have been trying to use the shadeRules in SBT to bring my jar file for my scala lambda down to size.  Currently, AWS requires the jar to be no bigger than 50megs.

The problem really comes into play because I am trying to access a phoenix database, a LOT of classes come along for the ride, and I am constantly hitting up against the 50meg size limit, and then hunting for files to delete (zap).

I feel there has to be an more automated process to do this.  Am i just missing something?  right now I update my jar, upload to AWS, get the error for which files I am missing and add them (almost all of my shadeRules are keeps, and then zap to delete unneeded files inside those libraries). This is a slow, long, boring process.

Thanks

Thanks

EDIT:

As asked, here are my added libraries:

```
libraryDependencies += "software.amazon.awssdk" % "ec2" % "2.5.60"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.11.313"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "3.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "4.14.3-HBase-1.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.4.10"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.4.10"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.12"
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with your `build.sbt`? You may be packaging some libraries that are already provided by AWS

Comment: Have you considered getting rid of the events library?  You'll need to parse the incoming event (I'm guessing from DynamoDB) but it means that you won't have a dependency on version1 of the SDK.

Comment: The 50MB limit is only for uploading to lambda directly. You can upload to S3 and then publish the lambda from S3 if your size is over the direct upload limit. See https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-aws-lambda-deployment-limits-9a8384b0bec3

Comment: I'm doing two pretty simple queries, one in DynamoDb and one in Phoenix.  The part that is complexing is the sheer amount of files needed for this (hbase-server just for a query!?)

Comment: What is the relation between Dynamodb and Phoenix ? How do you deploy the lambda ?

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading it via S3, real limit is 250 MB uncompressed.
Create S3 deployment bucket.

```
sam package \
        --profile ${PROFILE} \
        --region ${REGION} \
        --template-file template.yaml \
        --s3-bucket ${S3_BUCKET} \
        --output-template-file ./build/package.yaml
```

```
sam deploy \
    --profile ${PROFILE} \
    --region ${REGION} \
    --template-file ./build/package.yaml \
    --stack-name ${APPLICATION}-lambda \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

Note: Try to minimise pacakge size it reflects during cold start.
Verify one more time your package if it has some extra dependencies included.

If you list you entire dependency tree ,we could give you better hints.
`sbt "inspect tree clean"`

Comment: I think the real answer in the end is not to use Scala with Lambdas.

Comment: @Limey  Well we use java lambdas with max size on 20 MB and it works pretty well, I believe should be the same with Scala, try nodejs or python for smaller package size

Comment: @Limey If you share a sample project with all dependencies without actual code I am sure there will be a better direction.